# How to wire 4way hot at 4way

Tags: wiring

How to wire 4 way switch, Hot at 4 way and light fed from 3 way on end. I have found similar picture by searching however it also fed light from 4 way.

[image]

Comment: Are you running new wiring for this, or is the wiring already in the walls?

Comment: It's already there.

Comment: If its to much trouble I can pull the wire out and put the hot into the light.

Comment: You can't add individual wires unless they are all already in conduit, but that is unlikely.  If your cable has 3 wires and you need 4, you pull a 4-wire cable  and yank out the 3.  Honestly you are better off with the power cable coming into a switch, as it satisfies a neutral requirement.  Do you currently have /3 cables from the 4-way to the other two 3-way locations?

Comment: Its not in conduit. Its romex. Its 3 wire from first box to second box 3w out to 3rd box. At 2 box is where hot got fed into. Feed for light is at box 3.

Comment: Essentially the same as picture except light would be on the far right.

Answer (score 2):

basically like this, with romex there will be an earth wire replacing the metal conduit so be sure to hook that up at each junction and to each box if metal,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the feed to the light to the right box then you can

In the center box swap the white on connection 1 going to the right with the black going to the right and remove the marking on it. Wirenut that white with the white from the feed.

In the switch on the right the red and black from the center go to the NO and NC contacts and the black to the light to the common. Remove the making from white and connect to white to the light.

[image]